# Randomly blitting in Pygame

Tags: python, python-2.7, random, pygame

im making a basic pygame and I was wondering if anyone can help me out

so after a certain amount of time a power-up scrolls down the screen but I cant get it to work

here is the method im using:

```
def random_event(self):
    self.force_img_r = self.force_img.get_bounding_rect()
    self.rnd_x = random.randint(5,315)
    self.force_img_r.x = self.rnd_x
    self.force_img_r.y += 3
    screen.blit(self.force_img,(self.rnd_x, self.force_img_r.y))
```

all its doing is the image is blinking for a split second then nothing

can anyone tell me why its not working!?

Comment: Is force the velocity that gets added to the location, every update?

Comment: no force field is what im blitting so i called it force it should move 3 pixels each update

Answer (score -1):

In pygame you usually have a main loop that cleans the screen on every iteration, that's probably why you only see a blink, you draw and in the next loop you clean again.

To work arround this, in pygame events should only update game state, and draw the screen on every loop according to the current state.

Some pseudocode:

```
# Main Loop
while True:

    # Process events
    #   -> Update game state

    # Clean screen
    # Draw current state to the screen

    # Update or flip display

    # Keep framerate (clock.Tick())
```

You can call external classes/methods/functions, but you should always keep this structure at the main loop.

Comment: i know how to make a pygame the game is pretty much done the code i posted is a method within the game class and it is put into the loop every 20 seconds

Comment: The function you posted it's called `random_event` and you are drawing inside it, so it seems you are not separating event processing from drawing. Perhaps you should post more code to get a better answer.